# In Powerpoint 2019, stop Ctrl+B from opening font dialog instead of toggling bold font

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hotkeys

**Edit**: My bad, it was caused by Autohotkey, which remapped Ctrl+B to Ctrl+Shift+F to enable use of Ctrl+B for bold text on the German version of Office 2010.

---

Using Powerpoint 2019, the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> is supposed to toggle **bold** formatting, but it opens the "Font" dialog instead. Is there anyway to restore the normal behavior?

Note: It is currently a fresh installation of Office 365, on a device, where MS Office wasn't previously installed. The behavior affects *only* Powerpoint.

---

#### Bold being bound to "Ctrl+B" according to tooltip

[image]

#### The unwanted font-dialog

[image]

Comment: Did you perhaps save a template with this shortcut defined? Here's the MS document on shortcuts, and how to change or remove them, see if it helps: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d

Comment: @music2myear Somewhat embarassing... It was actually a consequence of having remapped Ctrl+B to Shift+Ctrl+F via Autohotkey to allow using Ctrl+B in the German version of Office 2010 at work.

Comment: @music2myear Also, in Office 2019 the option to redefine hotkeys seems to have been removed.

Comment: Huh, it appears that is the case indeed. I'll have to do some research on that.

Answer (score 1):

See above. I sabotaged myself with autohotkey.